# Combining "If" Statements

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an excel macro that when a part number is scanned into the spreadsheet (in column A), it will automatically open up a PDF document related to that part number. I've got it working for the first cell I want to look at, but am stuck after that. I can add a bunch of "if" statements but there has to be a way to clean it up rather than having hundreds of "if" statements. I need to start in cell A9 and continue to cell A209. Below is what I have so far. Any help in combining these into a simpler code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim varCellvalue As String

If Target.Address = "$A$9" Then
    varCellvalue = Range("A9").Value
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "F:\ITEM PART MASTER\" & varCellvalue & "\" & varCellvalue & " Pack.pdf"
End If

If Target.Address = "$A$10" Then
    varCellvalue = Range("A10").Value
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "F:\ITEM PART MASTER\" & varCellvalue & "\" & varCellvalue & " Pack.pdf"
End If

If Target.Address = "$A$11" Then        
    varCellvalue = Range("A11").Value
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "F:\ITEM PART MASTER\" & varCellvalue & "\" & varCellvalue & " Pack.pdf"     
End If
```

This could go on and on, but I figured there has to be a more efficient way of combining these into a simple statement.

Comment: Try to generate  range dynamically. Then you dont need the rest

Comment: I don't think you even need the If statement. It looks like you're always doing the same thing, only the `varCellvalue` changes.  Try replacing all of your `If` statements with just `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "F:\ITEM PART MASTER\" & target.value & "\" & target.value & " Pack.pdf"`

Comment: Thank you @BruceWayne. That worked exactly as intended! I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, all you need is something quite simple and short (see code below)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim varCellvalue As String

' run your code only if a cell inside the Range("A9:A11") has been changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A9:A11")) Is Nothing Then
    varCellvalue = Target.Value
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "F:\ITEM PART MASTER\" & varCellvalue & "\" & varCellvalue & " Pack.pdf"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: To save a line or two, @shawnjames could just take out he `varCellValue` variable and just use `Target.Value` directly in the hyperlink.  But nicely done!

Comment: @BruceWayne agree, but I'm trying to save some tracability to the original code in the post

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Select Case` instead

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim varCellvalue As String

Select Case Target.Address
  Case "$A$9"
    varCellvalue = Range("A9")
  Case "$A$10"
    varCellvalue = Range("A10")
  Case "$A$11"
    varCellvalue = Range("A11")
End Select

ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "F:\ITEM PART MASTER\" & varCellvalue & "\" & varCellvalue & " Pack.pdf"
```

Or you could do it faster since you are just inserting the value of the Target into the url.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "F:\ITEM PART MASTER\" & Target & "\" & Target & " Pack.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to limit this to a few cells, and not every range, then you can use an array to load the target cells, and just check if the target address is in there, then run your code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim varCellvalue As String
Dim targetCells() As Variant
targetCells() = Array("$A$9", "$A$10", "$A$11")

If (UBound(Filter(targetCells, Target.Address)) > -1) Then
    'This cell is in your array
    Debug.Print Target.Value
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "F:\ITEM PART MASTER\" & Target.Value & "\" & Target.Value & " Pack.pdf"
End If

End Sub
```